# stxxl save and read vector from disk file

Tags: c++, stxxl

I'm struggling in trying to use the stxxl library in a way, that I cannot only store the data from their vector structure into a file but also recover it from that file in a rerun of my program.

I found out that you can construct a vector from a file ( http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/classstxxl_1_1vector.html#a4d9029657cc11315cb77955fae70b877 ) but the class "file" only contains these functions ( http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/classstxxl_1_1file.html ) with no way (that I can see) to actually access an existing file with some given path.

Does someone who worked with this library before have an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stxxl::file` is an interface base class. Depending on your operating system, you want one of the derived classes

- `stxxl::syscall_file` for UNIX, Linux, and Mac OS X using POSIX `read` and `write`,
- `stxxl::wincall_file` for Windows, or
- `stxxl::linuxaio_file` for Linux using the `SYS_io_*` asynchronous I/O syscalls (see `man 7 aio` for details). This requires STXXL 1.4.1.

You can use the `stxxl::create_file` function to decide at runtime which backend to use. Set the `io_impl` parameter to `"syscall"`, `"wincall"`, or `"linuxaio"`, respectively.

Comment: Examples with `stxxl::syscall_file` also work on Windows. Is this because it is POSIX compatible? Would changing to `stxxl::wincall_file` make things more efficient?